# PIL - empty PSD image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, layer, psd

I'm trying to load this PSD image with Python Imaging Library.
http://www.2shared.com/photo/JjSY7dN-/BG1.html

I'm not very familiar with layered images. Can someone check to see what's the issue? The image appears to be completely transparent. Opening it in my image editor I noticed that the only layer in the image was hidden, I could unhide it to see the colors.
When I load the image with PIL, I get the same issue, but it seems that PIL consolidates the layers into one and I can't do the same as in my image editor. Or maybe there's something I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

PIL provides only very rudimentary hooks into the PSD format.  It doesn't support writing or much in the way of manipulation.  Your image layer is not shown, so it results in a transparent image.  You'll need something more advanced to modify the PSD.

Here's all there is about the PSD format in PIL: http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-psd.htm
Soon to be available here: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/format-psd.htm